# How can I only normalize numeric variables with Pyspark ml?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with both numerical and categorical data.

In order to fit a Random Forest Classifier, I do the next transformations:

- StringIndexer() to index categorical features
- VectorAssembler() to get the dense vector
- StandarScaler() to normalize numerical features.

The question is that I only want to normalize “var1”, “var2” and “var3” (the numerical features). The problem is that StandarScaler() needs a dense vector as an input, like  “features”, so my question is:

•   Is there any way to normalize ONLY numerical features?

And if not…

•   Does it make sense to have a features column with the categorical data normalized? 
I mean,  does the Random Forest correctly understand the information with the categorical data normalized? Is it okay to do this?

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import *
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([[11.1,13.2,3,'blue',1],
                            [1.8,45.0,8,'green',1],
                            [5.0,1.78,11,'yellow',1],
                            [0.0,56.3,15,'orange',0],
                            [8.0,14.6,17,'purple',0]],['var1','var2','var3','cat1','label'])
df.show()

+----+----+----+------+-----+
|var1|var2|var3|  cat1|label|
+----+----+----+------+-----+
|11.1|13.2|   3|  blue|    1|
| 1.8|45.0|   8| green|    1|
| 5.0|1.78|  11|yellow|    1|
| 0.0|56.3|  15|orange|    0|
| 8.0|14.6|  17|purple|    0|
+----+----+----+------+-----+

indexer=StringIndexer(inputCol="cat1",outputCol="cat1_index").setHandleInvalid("keep")
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["var1","var2","var3","cat1_index"], outputCol="assembler")
scaler = MinMaxScaler(inputCol="assembler",outputCol="features")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[indexader,assembler,scaler])
df_transf = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)
df_transf.select("features").show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1.0,0.20946441672780633,0.0,0.25]                               |
|[0.16216216216216217,0.7927366104181952,0.35714285714285715,0.75]|
|[0.45045045045045046,0.0,0.5714285714285714,1.0]                 |
|[0.0,1.0,0.8571428571428571,0.5]                                 |
|[0.7207207207207208,0.23514306676449012,1.0,0.0]                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```